# Prove that if y < z then x + y < x + z for Q and R (Rudin skipped it)

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, axioms

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin specified ***a definition***. It is very important because we often use it in convergence proofs. However, it's a definition, not an axiom. And it's not a part of the binary operator (>) defition. I think it's possible to derive it somehow.

[image]

Comment: But the properties specified in the Def holds for every *ordered filed*; thus, we can use them in every proof regarding ordered fields.

Comment: Well, what other properties do you have for an ordered field?  Because if you don't have any other properties, how would this be provable?

Comment: This can be checked directly from the definition of $+$ and $<$, but these definitions depend on the precise construction of $\mathbb{R}$. IIRC, Rudin discusses 2 possible constructions of $\mathbb{R}$, the Dedekind cut approach and the Cauchy sequence approach, and shows both produce ordered fields.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but I have just noticed that "preserves" is an anagram of "reverses", once you add a "p" (for positive). I find this rather pleasing.

Comment: Thanks Mark, indeed I see that the long Dedekind cut proof at the end of the chapter proofs that R is an ordered field. Now I have more motivation to dive deeper into it

Comment: Curiously for $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, we have $0\leq m<n$ implies $m+1\leq n$, but also $n<n+1$ gives $m+1<n+1$ by transitivity of $<$. Then apply induction from here for a result similar to (i). Next, considering $0<m$ implies $0+m<m+m$ by the first result, we get $0<2m$. Induction gives a result similar to (ii)... I couldn't quite use this to prove the case for $\mathbb{R}$ directly (or for fields with $char(F) = 0$), but I suspect the next step would be to extend this to integers, then rationals, then reals via Dedekind maybe. Of course, the easier route is to just accept as definition haha.